# How do I Add border to text in inputfield

Tags: css, text, input, border, addition

I'm trying to find out how I can customize the text in a input field with css.
What I want to do is to add a border to the text written in the input field.

I can customize the font-family, font-size with the "input" in css but when I add a border it applies on the input field.

[JSfiddle trying to explain what I mean](http://jsfiddle.net/6Gevu/)

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Add border to this text" />

body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid #000
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

I've tried searching but didn't find anything useful, I'm sure this is easy and hopefully someone can help me.

Thank you

Edit: I'm trying to get the text in the input field like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKaUI.png

Comment: how about `text-shadow` - http://jsfiddle.net/6Gevu/11/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

notice I have put an ID attribute on your input: id="myInput"

```
    <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Add border to this text" />
... and not the inputwindow itself.
```

and your CSS is below. Notice the #myInput::-webkit-input-placeholder. #myInput targets your input box, and the webkit bit is for google..moz is for firefox, and ms-input-placeholder is for Internet Explorer:

```
body {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

input {
    border: 1px solid #000
    width: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
        font-size: 20px;
}


#myInput::-webkit-input-placeholder {

 border-style:solid;
border-width:medium;
}
#myInput:-moz-placeholder {
 border-style:solid;
border-width:medium;
}
#myInput:-ms-input-placeholder {
 border-style:solid;
border-width:medium;
}
```

To change the font of the placeholder text to stroke, try this:

```
#myInput::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color: white;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;

}
#myInput:-moz-placeholder {
color: white;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}
#myInput:-ms-input-placeholder {
color: white;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}
```

Comment: First I'd like to thank you Gray for trying to help me.
However, I think I've failed with explaining exactly what I want.

I want to "stroke"(like in photoshop) the text in the input field. Like in this picture: http://i.imgur.com/zmBphb1.png
Maybe border wasn't a correct word?

I hope you understand what I'm trying to explain. Thank you again

Comment: Thank you. I noticied it only applies for the placeholder. So if I write anything in the textbox it doesn't work. I tried changing "placeholder" to "value" in css but i didnt work, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your css code is not correct: you forgot the ;

http://jsfiddle.net/6Gevu/10/

```
input {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```