# Add border to text of input field

Tags: css, wordpress, input

I am trying to get the following to display the word "Search" with a border underneath the text itself (not the input window). I attempted to use the CSS `placeholder` as found here [How do I Add border to text in inputfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346202/how-do-i-add-border-to-text-in-inputfield), but it will not work. Here is my input box (it is a search box for wordpress):

```
<input id="search" name="s" type="text" onfocus="if(this.value=='Search') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Search';" value="Search" />
```

I would be much obliged to whomever can give me a fix. I know that it is because I have `onfocus=` and `onblur=` instead of just `placeholder=`, but can't seem to figure it out.

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6Gevu/14/

Answer (score 1):

put a css line: text-decoration: underline;  when it says 'search' and remove that style when it's something else. Maybe by adding and removing a class (.underline) to the input field.

Comment: Thanks, but I need it to be border-bottom: 1px solid, not text-decoration: underline. I know its specific, but its required by the design

Comment: That requires some effort, maybe this is what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/HR5N8/406/

Comment: I'm not sure that that will do the trick, but I appreciate your assistance. Do you have any suggestion for further research into making this happen? Do I have to rely on JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `:after` pseudo-element to generate a border, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/RMJWH/

```
.search-border {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.search-border:after {
    content: ".";
    color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 2px;
    width: 238px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}
```

Comment: But that adds bottom border to the whole box, I just need the text itself with a bottom border

Comment: just the placeholder text ? or also the input text ?

Comment: The only thing to have the border is the 'Search' text itself. So, just the placeholder text

Answer (score 0):

You could enclose your input box into a div and style that div to look like your input box. Then force the input box to to only show the bottom border.

```
<div class="input-box"><input type="text" /></div>

.input-box
{
     /*your styles here*/
}

input
{
     border:0;
     border-bottom:/*some value*/
}
```